# Distributed Caching in Elixir

Tags: caching, elixir, ets

I am writing an Elixir app that requires a registry to store the mapping of which pid belongs to which user. I will have an GenServer per user in the app that will be supervised. I have the basic example working with one node using ETS but with 2+ nodes, I can't use ETS since it does not support clustering/replication. What are some other options for having a distributed cache? From doing some research, my options are using Database such as Redis or use Amensia.

Comment: This question is pretty old but I imagine you might have meant "Mnesia" instead of "Amensia" at the end of the last sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want duplicates across your cluster, you could simply register each GenServer globally.

```
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, [name: {:global, user_id}]
```

Then you can simply lookup `:global.whereis_name(user_id)` to get the pid. If the process dies, it's automatically unregistered. Here's the documentation for [Erlang's global module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html).

Comment: Note that the registration term (`user_id` in the example) can be any Erlang/Elixir term, not just atoms.

Comment: Would user_id be considered as atom? I read in erlang documentation that atom namespace/table is not garbage collected. So having lot of pids with named atom could cause overhead until the VM is restored.

Comment: You would probably use an integer, or string (uuid?), or however you uniquely identify your users (primary key in a database?). You wouldn't use an atom for exactly the reason you're saying - it wouldn't be garbage collected.

Comment: I would use a string which is uuid.

Comment: Then it would be garbage collected when appropriate.